# Cordova Android 2.3 SyntaxError: Parse error unknown reason

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm trying to get my cordova/phonegap app to run on android 2.3 and I keep receiving this error

```
file:///android_asset/www/scripts/gameStates/HomeState.js: Line 15 : SyntaxError: Parse error
```

which points to this line of code

```
templates.continue = !!this.game ? '<button id="continueGameButton">Continue    Game</button>' : '';
```

Removing the line seems to fix the issue, but I have no idea what about this line is causing the parse error. Any suggestions would be lovely :)

The whole project is online too if it helps identify the problem

src: https://github.com/lpaulger/cribbage-the-game/

src-file: https://github.com/lpaulger/cribbage-the-game/blob/DominantHand/app/scripts/gameStates/HomeState.js

Answer (score 0):

turns out 'continue' is a reserved word so it was most likely inserting a semi-colon after it causing the syntax error...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion